# Colon operator on constant attribute in MATLAB class

Tags: matlab, class, constants

I have a weird problem I can't solve and can't find any solution to on the internet:

```
classdef test
    properties(Constant)
        bla = {'Marker', 'o', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'b', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b'};
    end
end
```

Accessing `test.bla` with colon operator in command line WORKS: `test.bla{:}`. But it doesn't when I use it within another class:

```
classdef foo
    properties
    end
    
    methods
        function this = foo()
            test.bla
            
            a = test.bla;
            a{:}
            
            test.bla{:}            
        end
    end    
end
```

It's very cumbersome to use `a = test.bla; a{:}` all the time...

Comment: `test.bla{:}` is probably not what you intend to do. It actually returns multiple answers, as you can see from its output at the command-line. Can you post your code where you actually use your workaround with `a` for something. Note that `test.bla(:)` works in both places.

Comment: I actually want to do it since I want to use `plot(x, y, test.bla{:})` to expand as single arguments!

Comment: You could also define `bla` as structure where the fields are the property names, and then call the plot with `test.bla`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it does not work! I was really surprised.

I found out that you can use :

```
x = {test.bla(:)};
```

This will give you all of the elements.

Comment: Thanks but I need to use it as single function arguments, thus I'd have to use `x = {test.bla(:)}; my_function(x{:})` which is as painful (probably even a bit more :)) as using `x = test.bla; my_function(x{:})`... But okay, I didn't post this concerning my function call in the post above! Thanks though! Perhaps I found a matlab bug, yey! ;D

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot the upvoting. Actually, it's not really a solution, since you just affirmed what I posted yet, but though I'll accept it, otherwise I won't have a 100% acept rate anymore :):) Perhaps somebody else will eventually help out here in the future :)